# Use lazyColum inside the column has an error in the Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-compose-textfield

I have a lazyColumn which I want to use inside the column but I get the below error and app crashes:

> Nesting scrollable in the same direction layouts like LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()) is not allowed. If you want to add a header before the list of items please take a look on LazyColumn component which has a DSL api which allows to first add a header via item() function and then the list of items via items()

**lazyColumn codes, I have a list in this code:**

```
@Composable
fun UpScreenSection(
    modifier: Modifier,
    state: ProfileState,
    viewModel: ProfileViewModel
) {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp))

    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(24.dp)
    ) {
        if (!state.items.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            Box(
                modifier = modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                LazyColumn(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    items(state.items) { item ->
                        ProfileListItems(item = item, onItemClick = {
                            //TODO Navigate to specific screen
                            when (it.id) {
                                1 -> {
                                }
                                2 -> {
                                }
                                3 -> {
                                }
                                4 -> viewModel.navigate(ReferAFriendDestination.route())
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(24.dp))
}
```

**The above codes used inside the below composable codes:**

```
@Composable
fun ProfileContentSection(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: ProfileViewModel
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        val state = viewModel.state.value

        Column(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(state = scrollState)
        ) {
            AccountNameSection(modifier = modifier, viewModel = viewModel)
            UpScreenSection(modifier, state, viewModel)   // used above block codes
            DownScreenSection(modifier, context)
        }
        if (state.error.isNotBlank())
            SimpleSnackbar(
                text = state.error,
                modifier = modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
            )

        if (state.isLoading)
            Loading(modifier = modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter))

    }
}
```

how can I fix this error?

Note: I want to have a scrollable screen that has a list in it for small devices

Answer (score 11):

I found the solution.
I have to move every view that is out of the LayzyColumn, inside it.

Example:

```
@Composable
fun SampleScreen(){
    LazyColumn{
        item {
            // other views
        }

         items(state.items){listItem ->
          //Load list data 
         }

          item {
           //other views
          }
     }
}
```

With this code, I will have a screen that has a scrollable view.

Comment: Just in case someone wants to build a similar layout: You can just drop Box & Column in this example and it will work fine

Comment: Yeah, the `Box` and `Column` is unnecessary

Comment: To avoid the header item to scroll with the list items, replace item by stickyHeader: