# Jetpack Compose: nested LazyColumn / LazyRow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

I've read through similar topics but I couldn't find satisfactory result:

- [What is the equivalent of NestedScrollView + RecyclerView or Nested RecyclerView (Recycler inside another recycler) in Jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66908737/what-is-the-equivalent-of-nestedscrollview-recyclerview-or-nested-recyclerv)
- [Jetpack Compose: How to put a LazyVerticalGrid inside a scrollable Column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67919707/jetpack-compose-how-to-put-a-lazyverticalgrid-inside-a-scrollable-column)
- [Use lazyColum inside the column has an error in the Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69822392/use-lazycolum-inside-the-column-has-an-error-in-the-jetpack-compose)
- [Nested LazyVerticalGrid with Jetpack Compose](https://medium.com/bazaar-tech/nested-lazyverticalgrid-with-jetpack-compose-f50d1a8f7e6e)

**My use-case is:** to create a comments' list (hundreds of items) with possibility to show replies to each comment (hundreds of items for each item).

Currently it's not possible to do a nested `LazyColumn` inside another `LazyColumn` because Compose will throw an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was
> measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is
> disallowed. One of the common reasons is nesting layouts like
> LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()). If you want to add a
> header before the list of items please add a header as a separate
> item() before the main items() inside the LazyColumn scope. There are
> could be other reasons for this to happen: your ComposeView was added
> into a LinearLayout with some weight, you applied
> Modifier.wrapContentSize(unbounded = true) or wrote a custom layout.
> Please try to remove the source of infinite constraints in the
> hierarchy above the scrolling container.

The solutions provided by links above (and others that came to my mind) are:

- Using fixed height for internal `LazyColumn` - I cannot use it as each item can have different heights (for example: single vs multiline comment).
- Using normal `Column`s (not lazy) inside `LazyColumn` - performance-wise it's inferior to lazy ones, when using Android Studio's Profiler and list of 500 elements, normal `Column` would use 350MB of RAM in my app comparing to 220-240MB using lazy `Composables`. So it will not recycle properly.
- Using `FlowColumn` from Accompanist - I don't see any performance difference between this one and normal `Column` so see above.
- Flatten the list's data source (show both comments and replies as "main" comments and only make UI changes to distinguish between them) - this is what I was currently using but when I was adding more complexity to this feature it prevents some of new feature requests to be implemented.
- Disable internal `LazyColumn`'s scrolling using [newly added in Compose 1.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69328009/4385799) `userScrollEnabled` parameter - unfortunately it throws the same error and it's an intended behaviour (see [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232821173)).
- Using other ways to block scrolling (also to block it [programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66502400/4385799)) - same error.
- Using other `LazyColumn`'s `.height()` parameters like `wrapContentHeight()` or using `IntrinsicSize.Min` - same error.

Any other ideas how to solve this? Especially considering that's doable to nest lazy components in Apple's SwiftUI without constraining heights.

Comment: Check out [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ANt65eoNhQ&t=899s) youtube video about the topic as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68995732/3585796) for a basic example - shortly you can place your subcomments in a separate `item`/`items`. Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71709816/3585796) may be useful for building a dynamic items tree.

Comment: Thanks @Pylyp Dukhov for your input, it was helpful, the main difference between my implementation and your suggestions was using `forEachIndexed` with manual control of `item` and `items` instead of `itemsIndexed` that I was using. However, it breaks pagination implemented like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4FnYeYR_fo) as `itemsIndexed` has different (user-aware) index value comparing to `forEachIndexed` one). At the end, it seems I managed to mix both "mindsets" to use `itemsIndexed` for comments and `forEach` for replies.

Comment: you should use `key` parameter of `item`/`items` to specify a unique identifier for each item, also `itemContent` can improve performance if you specify different types depending on cell type (comment/reply)

Comment: Sad that this still doesn't have an answer. I have comment trees in my application and am still forced to use `Column` for the inner branches.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to build a tree using LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71667299/how-to-build-a-tree-using-lazycolumn-in-jetpack-compose)

Comment: This was answered by Phil here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71667299/how-to-build-a-tree-using-lazycolumn-in-jetpack-compose

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar use case and I have a solution with a single `LazyColumn` that works quite well and performant for me, the idea is to treat your data as a large `LazyColumn` with different types of elements.
Because comment replies are now separate list items you have to first flatten your data so that it's a large list or multiple lists.
Now for sub-comments you just add some padding in front but otherwise they appear as separate lazy items.
I also used a `LazyVerticalGrid` instead of LazyColumn because I've had to show a grid of gallery pictures at the end, you may not need that, but if you do, you have to use span option everywhere else as shown below.

You'll have something like this:

```
LazyVerticalGrid(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(6.dp),
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(3)
    ) {
        item(span = { GridItemSpan(3) }) {
            ComposableTitle()
        }
        items(
            items = flattenedCommentList,
            key = { it.commentId },
            span = { GridItemSpan(3) }) { comment ->
                ShowCommentComposable(comment) 
                //here subcomments will have extra padding in front
        }
        item(span = { GridItemSpan(3) }) {
            ComposableGalleryTitle()
        }
        items(items = imageGalleryList,
            key = { it.imageId }) { image ->
                ShowImageInsideGrid(image) //images in 3 column grid
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to prevent problems with nested `LazyColumn` or `LazyRow` components within a scrollable screen, where it's not always easy to determine the number of items in advance, you can implement a solution in your `ViewModel`. By creating a function that calculates the height of the `LazyColumn` dynamically based on the size of the list, you can ensure that the layout and scrolling behavior work smoothly."

This solution can help you avoid crashes and layout issues when dealing with nested scrollable components like `LazyColumn` or `LazyRow` within a scrollable screen.

Calculate `LazyColumn` Height on run time:

```
fun getHeightOfLazyColumn(numberOFItemsInlist: Int): Int 

{
        return if (size % numberOfItemsInEachRow == 0) (numberOFItemsInlist/numberOfItemsInEachRow) * heightingleIteminLazyColumn
        else return (((numberOFItemsInlist.toDouble() / 3.0) + 1) *  heighsingleIteminLazyColumn).toInt()
    }
```

**My function:**

```
fun getNumberDepartments(size: Int): Int {
    return if (size % 3 == 0) (size / 3) * 130
    else return (((size.toDouble() / 3.0) + 1) * 130).toInt()

}
```

After this Call this Function in your UI

```
LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        item {
            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.height(viewModel.getHeightOfLazyColumn(listOfItems.size))){
                item {
                    //content
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For cases where

- a flattened LazyColumn is undesirable, (for eg. the inner LazyColumn has a background that spans its items or something),
- and where that inner list is best represented by a LazyColumn (for eg. because you want item animations out of the box)

a workaround is to specify a fixed height for the inner LazyColumn, if it's possible to know it.  Either determine the desired height using a subcompose layout or similar, or if your items have fixes sizes, compute the total height manually.

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    LazyColumn {
        item {
            // ...
        }
        item {
            // We want to animate item placement which is only possible out of the box
            // with a LazyColumn. Nested scrollables are not allowed in Jetpack Compose
            // due to single layout pass requirements, however if we have a specified
            // height for the LazyCol it is allowed. So we must compute the expected
            // height ahead of time.
            val cardsHeightSum = CardHeight * cards.size
            val cardsPaddingSum = CardSpacing * (cards.size - 1)
            LazyColumn(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
                userScrollEnabled = false,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.Blue, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
                    .height(cardsHeightSum + cardsPaddingSum)
            ) {
                items(
                    count = cards.size,
                    key = { index -> cards[index].id },
                ) { index ->
                    MyCard(
                        model = cards[index],
                        modifier = Modifier.animateItemPlacement()
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use a customView thats implements a "RecyclerView" class and then put it on your compose fragment. I'll show you my solution, works pretty well for me.

[compose view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFqYN.png)

[customViewRecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gS11T.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUndc.png)

Of course you haves to create the adapter and the view for each item of the list, but I think you can do it without my help, good luck! :D

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: It is really a bad practice to use the androidview inside the compose in such case that there is better solution like using for/foreach

Answer (score -9):

```
LazyColumn {
  
  item {
    LazyRow {
      // your code
    }
  }

  items(yourList) {
    // your code  
  }

}
```